# AS3/Flash: XML-PHP or PHP-MySQL advise request

Tags: php, mysql, xml, actionscript-3

I need to create a Flash based application than must store data (and read also) in a database.

It will be dealing with about 500 records to fill and update a data grid with four columns.

Can it be done with pure AS3/XML/PHP or it's better to use MySQL?

Could you point to me to good tutorials or book?

I did buy an adobepress book (ActionScript 3 for Flash CS5) a couple of years ago but it only covers XML reading.

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have done the same as desktop app yet. The database is stored in a local XML file (My Documents/storage folder) that I can read/write without any problem.

I need to adapt the project for on-line use.

**UPDATE 2:**

I did find this files: http://www.kirupa.com/web/xml/examples/newseditor.htm

The tutorials has some errors but is very simple. I will test it's performance with 500 records (I need something like 250 records)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest to use MySQL. The idea is to use the PHP as bridge between AS3 and the database. Flash has native support of XML, but if it is possible for you use JSON. Here is a [short article](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/load-mysql-data-in-flash-with-as3-and-php) about that subject.

Comment: I have done the same as desktop app yet. The database is stored in a local XML file (My Documents/storage folder) that I can read/write without any problem. I need to develop an on-line version. Thanks for your help Krasimir.

Comment: In your article (really nice one) you say: "In line 24 I'm defining a random parameter that we will add to the URL to prevent the caching of the data." How this work?

Comment: Every time when you make a request to some url the browser caches the result. Next time when you try to make the same request the browser checks if there is result for the same url and returns it. Using different url every time prevent this. However, the cache has also expire time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll test the PHP/MySQL/Flash formula. I did fallow a tutorial years ago (Lee Brimellow, I think)